# Packages installation

Tags: package-management, software-installation

Good morning, 
I installed this morning on my computer the new version 20.04 LTS of Ubuntu. This is my first operating system other than windows, so I'm still a beginner in using it. My question is the following: can packages from previous versions of Ubuntu (18.04 for example) be installed on this new version? If yes, how can I make the packages "findable"?

For example I wanted to install the latest version of OpenFoam7 (an open source CFD sofware) but after following the installation procedure :

```
sudo sh -c "wget -O - https://dl.openfoam.org/gpg.key | apt-key add -"
sudo add-apt-repository http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get -y install openfoam7

An error message appears: "E: Cannot find the openfoam7 package."
```

I guess that's because this software is only compatible up to version 19.04. So do I have to wait for OpenFoam developers to release a version compatible with ubuntu 20.04?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You can wait, or alternatively, make it compatible with 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

For me it seems that can simply install OpenFOAM from [official repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/openfoam) as simple as:

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r "deb http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu focal main"
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openfoam
```

If you really need to use third-party repository - then change *focal* to *disco* as it is currently supported by OpenFOAM. Use commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://dl.openfoam.org/ubuntu disco main"
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/c/cgal/libcgal13_4.14-5_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ./libcgal13_4.14-5_amd64.deb

sudo apt-get install openfoam7
```