# Is it possible to install OpenFoam on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04

I was trying to follow the installation tutorials but it didn't work. Apparently there is versions of open Foam for Ubuntu 18.04 but not for the one that I have which is 20.04. Anyone can help me with that?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/a/1230326/66509

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to install the one released on 8th July 2019? If that didn't work, you will have to wait for the next update. They may not have made it compatible with Ubuntu 20.04 yet. That's probably the reason for the issue.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answers. I have just checked today the openFoam site, and they have already uploaded the installers for Ubuntu 20.04. With it I could install the program.

Comment: @JPablo Then mark something as the answer so others can find solutions easily.

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the openFoam site again, and they have uploaded the installers for Ubuntu 20.04 on 08.05.20. With it I could install the program

https://openfoam.org/news/ubuntu-20-04-lts/

Comment: Good to know. But you can't mark your own answer as the answer...

Answer (score 0):

Support for bionic, focal and groovy: [openfoam.com wiki](https://develop.openfoam.com/Development/openfoam/-/wikis/precompiled/debian)

For example,

```
curl -s https://dl.openfoam.com/add-debian-repo.sh | sudo bash
```

and then `sudo apt-get install openfoam-default`